# Variable Reference directory in code

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to have a user be able to type in the directory of another spreadsheet into a cell, then use that in my macro. In code like:

```
Range("X1") = Directory

Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = 'Directory'!RC)
```

When Range("X1") is where the user types in the Directory of the desired reference file

Comment: Maybe add a sample value for `Directory` - will that be a full path to an Excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make user choose a file from a dialog box by

```
range("X1").value = application.getopenfilename
dim MyDir as string
MyDir = range("X1").value ' and use MyDir variable in code from now on
```

Hope that was what you were looking for, cheers

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to reference a separate sheet in the same workbook. If that's the case then you can try:
`Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "'" & Range("X1").Value & "'!RC..."`

However, this works very similarly to the `=INDIRECT()` worksheet function which may be a better solution especially if this is a static formula. To use this, in cell A1 enter:
`=INDIRECT("'" & X1 & "'!RC...")`

You can read more about the INDIRECT function [here.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/151323)